# Ubuntu One Authentication failed

Tags: authentication

Ubuntu one fails to authenticate from my new Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit installation but I can access my account from a browser.

I've tried resetting the password several times and I've also tried reinstalling ubuntu one as per the directions given in the ubuntu one website.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try this [what should I do if Ubuntu One authentication fails?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-should-i-do-if-authentication-fails-auth_failed-state/)

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this is error is the root SSL certificate for valicert.com is not completely installed on your computer.

Please open the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T);

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ca-certificates
```

Logout and login (Restart preferred) and Try UbuntuOne account once more.

You may read this page [Why am I getting an "authentication failed" error?](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/why-am-i-getting-an-the-authentication-failed-error-on-windows/)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.