# Authentication failure Ubuntuone

Tags: ubuntu-one

I suddenly got the `File sync error (auth failed (AUTH_FAILED)` message on Ubuntu 13.10. It worked flawlessly for several months.
I tried all methods reported in

- [What should I do if authentication fails? (AUTH_FAILED state)](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/faq/what-should-i-do-if-authentication-fails-auth_failed-state/)
- [Ubuntu One - Sync error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/42429/ubuntu-one-sync-error/42475#42475)
- [Ubuntu One Authentication failed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164195/ubuntu-one-authentication-failed)

I can connect (so username and password are OK) but it doesn't sync.

It says

`File Sync in progress" and "Getting information, please wait" and that is all.
Later it says "File sync is disconnected" and still "Getting information, please wait`

So, where is the problem ?

Comment: I have nothing changed since I asked the question but suddenly it works again. Apparently it was a problem of the ubuntuone server as the meanwhile vanished comment suspected. So, if all methods above (see the links) fail, it might be a server problem.